# I am getting the SID in ADSI edit, Could anyone please let me know what is SID belongs to and how to convert the SID through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

In ADSI edit I am getting the SID.

Could I please let me know what is that SID belongs to and how to convert the SID through PowerShell. I want to add some windows accounts in Roles via powershell. So I cant do when SID is there. I want to do these changes in member server. Not in domain controller.  Attached the screenshot below for the reference.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: `CN=Configuration,CN={<GUID>}` is _not_ a SID, it's a Distinguished Name

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Thanks for the reply Mathias. Are you able to see my screenshot which I have attached ? May I Know what is GUID ?

Comment: It's the object guid for the crossRef entry in the connected domain controller's partition table - my guess is that ADSIEdit fails to resolve it because of the non-standard ports you're using

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hi Mathias. thanks for the explanation.  Actually its not an domain. its an member server. That port number is ADLDS port number. Could you please give me an idea ? how to automate the GUID which was listed in the screenshot